# “this” inside an Object pointing to an empty Object

Tags: javascript

So I have this JavaScript code:

```
var obj={
   a: “Chris”,
   b: this
   };console.log(obj.b);  //{}
```

The console.log return an empty object rather than the object with variable a and b.

Anyone know why?

Thank you very much!

Comment: this should also in quotes, like 'chris' other wise this will be javascript/jquery object

Comment: They *want* an object.  Putting "this" in quotes would be a string.  (Also there is no jquery here, just js)

Comment: What is expected result? A circular reference to `obj`?

Comment: @guest271314 the output  I expected is an object with property a and b inside while what it return is just an empty object {}.

Comment: The same object?

Answer (score 0):

If this code is in the global scope, which I assume it is, `this` points to the global object (whatever it is). If you want it to point to the object itself, you cannot do it in the literal, you need to assign it later (after you create the object itself).

Comment: I don't think so - the global object wouldn't be empty

Comment: It does not have to be the global. It is the upper scope, which may or may not be empty.